# Why can't I open yahoo's dapper (open.dapper.net/)

Tags: yahoo-api

**Question**:

Why is dapper.net telling me that its having an internal server error when it appears that no one else is?

**Overview:**

I can't access yahoo's dapper.net (http://open.dapper.net/dapp-factory.jsp). I can reach the page "http://open.dapper.net", but not the actual program "/dapp-factory.jsp" When I click the link it loads for a long time and eventually says "An internal server error occurred. Please try again later." However, judging by other forums other users are not having this problem- including those on stackoverflow- and yahoo has not put forward any notice.

**Things I did/ tried:**

1. Searched on other forums, and posted this question on yahoo's forum (http://forum.dapper.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5946&p=9720&hilit=internal+server+error#p9720) with no luck.
2. After having some other strange things happen related to chrome, i tried to use dapper.net on firefox and ie, and the same thing continues to happen. I tried to access the site from another computer, and it still happens.

**Background that may/may not be relevant:**

About a month ago dapper.net, (a popular online software that scrapes web pages to create rss feeds and other types of files from different web data) went down for a while, other users noted it on forums, and then the site went back up. Apparently it was a routine update. After the update, the site was live, and i began to have problems. the site would allow me to get to /dapp-factory.jsp but after trying to select content for scraping, it would eternally load the page with a "there was an error in the creation process of this dapp" in  the background.

*this question was previously closed because it was originally too vague, so I have tried to clean it up. Please let me know how I can specify further if this is still the case.
Thank you

Comment: Anything? Is this just not the appropriate place for this question? Is anyone else able to use yahoo dapper (http://open.dapper.net/) services? Even if I just know that other folks are experiencing the same thing its helpful.

Comment: it's sad you didn't get an answer. I'm exploring for the answer and I shall continue to explore.